# Uninstall and reinstall SharePoint Foundation and no Standalone Option

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint Server that I uninstalled. (I just did it through add-remove programs and uninstall)

Then when I tried to re-install Sharepoint foundations 2010 (the same version I uninstalled) it would seem to work correclty, but it would not give me an option for Stand Alone. Only giving me an option for Existing Web Farm or New Web Farm.

I have tried to delete the instances of SQL Server (Sharepoint) but still getting this problem.

I have Windows 2010 Server (same as Windows 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Stand Alone" option. I just installed a fresh SharePoint 2010 and only had the options for "Existing Server Farm" or "New Server Farm". As explained in the same dialog: Go for "New Server Farm" when you are installing it on a single server (stand alone).